# Online Ad Posting plugin for WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

is there an online advertising WordPress plugin out there that allows people to sign-up and post items they wish to sell under different categories? My client wants me to build something similar to Craigslist, it will not have a cart or checkout functionality. People will come to the site and browse items and manually contact the seller using the contact number listed on the item page.

Each user will have their account where they can manage their items, edit profile info, change profile picture, and if possible - send messages to other users?. All of this will have to be on the front-end, The admin should be able to manage all user items, user messages, user profile info, and site wide settings.

I tried using WooCommerce but the adding of item is from the back-end which is not what my client wants, users should never know that the website is running in WordPress.

I know there's a lot of features needed, but I need a base plugin that could at least cover most of the requirements then will just try to work on the rest by extending the plugin.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [WP Trade](http://carlofontanos.com/product/wp-trade/). It covers all the requirements you need for your project; Messaging, User Profile, Item Listing, Managing items, etc.  All of these is on the front-end.

Wp Trade is a Theme Software, you can read more about it here : http://carlofontanos.com/product/wp-trade/